# Passing files from my server instance to worker instance to run

Tags: java, openstack

I'm new to programming using the open stack API. I want to send a .java file to my worker instance to execute. How can I achieve that. I have looked all over for an explicit description but could not find one. I was able to pass in bash command using base64 encoder to create my java folder, but how do I send my java file 'toDo.java' to my worker and place it inside the java folder and execute it? Your answer will help me a lot.

```
    public String createWorker() {
    String script = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(("#!/bin/bash\n" + "sudo mkdir /home/ubuntu/java").getBytes());

    ServerCreate server = Builders.server()
            .name("Slave Machine")//instance name
            .flavor("406352b0-2413-4ea6-b219-1a4218fd7d3b")//flavour id
            .image("592e8ddb-03ba-407f-92a0-dec08866457e")// -image id
            .keypairName("myPemKey")//key pair name
            .addSecurityGroup("7cae225c-8deb-4e3b-9357-904438615a42")//Security group ID (allow SSH)
            .userData(script)
            
            .build();//build the VM with above configuration
            
    return os.compute().servers().boot( server).getId();
    
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two approaches.

You could encode the Java file and have the user-data Bash script unpack the encoded text and store it in a file on the instance. Or you could create a [MIME Multipart Archive](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/format.html) and submit it as user-data.

The first approach is probably much simpler, for example

```
base64 -d >toDo.java <<END
.... encoded Java ....
END
```

The MIME approach is more elegant in my opinion, but requires a bit of investigation into the capabilities of cloudinit. You would create a cloudinit [write_files](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html#write-files) module to deposit the Java file on the instance, and your Bash script, then combine them into a single MIME file.